# Why doesn't the same group render a correct line chart and corresponding range chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8yf7j3k6/11/

I'm trying to bring in a similar representation of my data for my range chart so that I can scrub on the range chart, but use the tooltip in the actual line chart of circulation data. Currently, I think I have two issues that are breaking my crossfilter and causing the range chart to look screwy:

1. If I use the standard group generated by crossfilter, I end up with a value that's (circulation data * number_of_regions_in_which_magazine_was_circulated). To bypass this, I created a map that keeps track of the number of regions, and divides the represented values. I could not figure out how to create a group for this, and handle it at the data level. As a result, I'm just doing the correction at the render step - could this be the cause of my woes?
2. I am using the exact same group for the line chart and the range chart. In the [NASDAQ sample](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) they appear to process the data differently, but it seems like they're just binning it differently, not doing a dramatic change. I don't understand why my graph has such a dramatic negative value at point zero.

Code for the offending charts below. Note that there's some boilerplate to muck through in the fiddle because there's no CDN for dateformat

```
    lineChart1
      .width(lineChart1Width-50)
      .height(lineChart1Height-50)
      .xUnits(d3.timeMonths)
      .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80 })
      .dimension(dimension1)
      .rangeChart(lineChart1Range)
      .group(circulationGroup1)
      .colors(colorScales.blue[colorScales.blue.length - 1])
      .elasticY(true)
      .brushOn(false)
      .valueAccessor(function (d) {
          return d.value / circulationValuesMap[d.key]
      })
      .title(function (d) {
          return `${d.key.format('mmm dd, yyyy')}\nCirculation: ${d.value / circulationValuesMap[d.key]} `
      })
      .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(1925, 0, 1), new Date(1927, 0, 1)]))
      .render()


    lineChart1Range
      .width(getWidth('line-chart-1-range')) /* dc.barChart('#monthly-volume-chart', 'chartGroup'); */
      .height(40)
      .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 80})
      .dimension(dimension1)
      .group(circulationGroup1)
      .valueAccessor(d => d.value / circulationValuesMap[d.key])
      .centerBar(true)
      .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(1925, 0, 1), new Date(1927, 0, 1)]))
      .round(d3.timeMonth.round)
      .alwaysUseRounding(true)
      .xUnits(() => 200);

    lineChart1Range.yAxis().ticks(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your CSS.

This rule applies to **every** first child of **any** element that is inside a `.line-chart-container`, also to the brush overlay.

```
.line-chart-container :nth-child(1) {
  height: 15em;
}
```

This is also true for the `:nth-child(2)`.

Replacing the 2 CSS height rules for the actual `div` elements

```
#line-chart-1 {
  height: 15em;
}
#line-chart-1-range {
  height: 2em;
}
```

removes the 2 large bars.

Also your line chart and range chart are not aligned, they have different widths and margins.

```
lineChart1Range
  //.width(getWidth('line-chart-1-range')) /* dc.barChart('#monthly-volume-chart', 'chartGroup'); */
  .width(lineChart1Width-50)
  .height(40)
  //.margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 80})
  .margins({top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80})
  .dimension(dimension1)
  .group(circulationGroup1)
  .valueAccessor(d => d.value / circulationValuesMap[d.key])
  .centerBar(true)
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(1925, 0, 1), new Date(1927, 0, 1)]))
  .round(d3.timeMonth.round)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .xUnits(() => 200);
```

All the bars have tool tips, you can't see them because the brush is catching all the mouse events. Maybe it is possible to disable tool tips for this chart